# How do I rotate a diagram in canvas while keeping the numbers upright?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm tyring to rotate a diagram in canvas around its center while keeping the letters upright. I'm trying to use   ctx.rotate(#) but it's rotating the entire diagram using what appears to be the left side of the canvas as the center.

The following link offers a visual: I want it to look like the green, not the red, as it currently does with my code. [Visual Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Oro.png)

The following is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxarcag/143/

And my code is below:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {
  // layer1/Line
  ctx.rotate(00);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(75.1, 7.7);
  ctx.lineTo(162.9, 7.7);
  ctx.stroke();
  function WordSelector1() {
  var word = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
  return random;
}
  var x = WordSelector1();
  // layer1/P
  ctx.font = "12.0px 'Myriad Pro'";
    ctx.rotate(0);
  ctx.fillText(x, 60.0, 10.0);
}
 });
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing rotated graphs in canvas is somewhat easy once you know how to move the origin (0,0) to another point and then rotating the axes around it.

I added some comments in the code as not to repeat code and explanations.

I also moved the functions out of the `$(document).ready` and changed some numbers for more rounded values.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {
  ctx.font = "12.0px 'Myriad Pro'";
  var angle = Math.random()*150; //Run more times to see other angles
    
  //This translates the 0,0 to the center of the horizontal line
  ctx.translate(100, 100);
  
  //This draws the original straight line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-50, 0);  //The coordinates are relative to the new origin
  ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  //Draw the first letter
  var x = WordSelector1();
  ctx.fillText(x, -60, 0);

  //This section draws the rotated line with the text straight

  //Rotate the canvas axes by "angle"
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-50, 0); //The relative coordinates DO NOT change
  ctx.lineTo(50, 0); //This shows that the axes rotate, not the drawing
  ctx.stroke();

  var x = WordSelector1();
  ctx.translate(-60,0); //The origin must now move where the letter is to be placed
  ctx.rotate(-angle * Math.PI/180); //Counter-rotate by "-angle"
  ctx.fillText(x, 0, 0); //Draw the letter
}

function WordSelector1() {
  var word = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
  return random;
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

One warning: after everything is drawn the axes end parallel to the canvas borders because it was rotated by -angle, but the origin is where the last letter was placed. You may want to use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` to avoid having to revert translations and rotations.

Comment: That is so helpful! Works beautifully. I appreciate your taking the time to put the comments in the code, too, because I'm trying to actually learn this rather than just getting it to work. Thanks!